# Why is the visits counter on the Google analytics report site stays on 0?

Tags: google-analytics

I've created a simple Google analytics [test site](http://ec2-75-101-145-114.compute-1.amazonaws.com/Test/TestGA.html) that has events (on the buttons) and log visits upon entering the page. The status in the Google analytics report site is set to "Receiving Data".

Why is the visits counter on the Google analytics report site stays on 0?

Here is the site's source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-12158271-3");
        pageTracker._trackPageview('/TestGA.html');
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Click the buttons to test GA...</div>
    <input type="button" value="clickA" onclick="pageTracker._trackPageview('/TestGA.html/a');" />
    <input type="button" value="clickB" onclick="pageTracker._trackPageview('/TestGA.html/b');" />
    <input type="button" value="clickC" onclick="pageTracker._trackPageview('/TestGA.html/c');" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you waited long enough? (IIRC Google Analytics is refreshed once a day, I mean you have to wait tomorrow to have todays figures).

Comment: I have visited and clicked those buttons, you can try again later :D

Comment: S.Mark, Thanx for the clicks, but the visit counter still remains on 0. I'll wait the recommended 24 hours to see if it makes a change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Google Analytics goes to some lengths to make sure your own visits aren't counted. Find someone else to visit the site.

Comment: Can I fake other person's visit by using Firefox's Private Browsing mode?

Comment: You will have to give it a try. Or you can open a question in GA's support group.

Answer (score 0):

move your tracker at the end of the page for performance issues